# Create multiple size images from one image upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I am facing problem with multiple image creation with codeigniter image_lib. Here is my code. Problem is only original image is uploading but not the others like thumbs, medium, large as defined in array.

My controller code is:

```
function do_upload() {

    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => 2000
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();


    $image_sizes = array(
        'thumb' => array(150, 100),
        'medium' => array(300, 300),
        'large' => array(800, 600)
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

foreach ($image_sizes as $resize) {

    $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '-' . $resize[0] . 'x' . 
    $resize[1],
        'maintain_ration' => true,
        'width' => $resize[0],
        'height' => $resize[1]
    );

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and don't forget to clear the cache...

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config = array(
'allowed_types'     => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', //only accept these file types
'max_size'          => 2048, //2MB max
'upload_path'       => $this->original_path //upload directory
```

);

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$image_data = $this->upload->data(); //upload the image

//your desired config for the resize() function
$config = array(
'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'], //path to the uploaded image
'new_image'         => $this->resized_path, //path to
'maintain_ratio'    => true,
'width'             => 128,
'height'            => 128
);

//this is the magic line that enables you generate multiple thumbnails
//you have to call the initialize() function each time you call the resize()
//otherwise it will not work and only generate one thumbnail
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();

$config = array(
'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'],
'new_image'         => $this->thumbs_path,
'maintain_ratio'    => true,
'width'             => 36,
'height'            => 36
);
//here is the second thumbnail, notice the call for the initialize() function again
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

}